# What is a married girl's parents' home called?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, american-english

Is there any name for a girl's parents' home in English language? I'm asking this because my language has the term "Maika," which connotes her (married girl's) parents' home.

Comment: Colloquially you would say something like "I'm going round to the in-laws'", the usage of the possessive as a destination implying their home. "In-laws" most often refers to the parents-in-law, that is to say the parents of one's spouse.

Comment: That i know :) but i want to know what would a married girl call her parent's home ?

Comment: "My parents' house" :)

Comment: Generally just *parent's house* or *the in-laws (house)*. No difference husband or wife.

Comment: The tag [tag:american-english] suggests that desired answers are supposed to be a word/phrase in current use in contemporary American English, so I'll leave this phrase here: ***parental abode***. Considering that *home*, *house*, *place* are common words, using *abode* could achieve a better effect since it signifies an unexpected usage. An example from *Ancient Indian Tradition & Mythology, Volume 33*: "A women who listens to this with devotion and is sanctified by the lord shall be honoured in her parental abode as well as in the abode of her husband." (Note: this word is used in AmE, too.)

Answer (score 9):

American English doesn't have a specific word for this. A person visiting their spouse's parents' house would probably say something along the lines of:

> - My in-laws' house
> - My spouse's parents' house
> - [Spouse's name]'s childhood home

...depending on context. (Someone's parents' house may not be their childhood home, after all.)

There's no differentiation in how a married person (male or female) would refer to their own parents' house, as opposed to a single person. You'd just say "my parents' house", or "the house where I grew up", or something like that.

I've heard the concept referred to as "the natal home" - referring to your family's house at the time when you were born - but I don't think that's common  colloquially. I think I've only heard psychologists and the like refer to it that way.

Answer (score 7):

In Australia any adult (male or female) would refer to the home they grew up in as their "family home".  This is usually used formally as in:

"My parents are selling the family home".

"We are celebrating Christmas at my wife's family home".

Informally, or if the parents no longer live in the childhood home we would just call it the 'parent's home' or 'Mum and Dad's place'.

"My parents are preparing their home for sale".

"We are celebrating Christmas at Mum and Dad's place this year".

I do not know of a single word with this connotation.

Answer (score -1):

English word for Married girl's parents' home (in Hindi it is called 'Maika')  is...

"Parental abode"
        or
"Maternal home"

Comment: Welcome to ELL! These sound plausible, but can you add a citation for either of these that shows this particular usage?

Comment: Those terms make sense to me, but I don't think you'd hear anyone in the US saying them in conversation.